# How can I change the locale?

Tags: raspbmc, locale

I'm having problems displaying some of "special" characters via SSH running Raspbmc, such as the ellipsis ("…") and Asian characters. Both are displayed as "?". I'm not sure if my locale is set up incorrectly.

When I first SSHed into the Pi, I installed `en_AU.utf8`, and selected it as default. It doesn't seem to have worked.

```
$ locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

I tried to set up the locale again using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`, and selected `en_AU.UTF-8` as default, but the output to `locale` did not change after this.

I also tried deleting `~/.configureduser`, relogging in by SSH, and repeating the configuration at first SSH. In addition to `en_AU.utf8`, I tried installing `en_GB.utf8` and `en_US.utf8` too (but selecting `en_AU.utf8` as default). This also failed. How do I change the locale in Raspbmc?

---

### EDIT

As per [Steve Robillard](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/56/steve-robillard)'s [suggestion](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19854/how-can-i-change-the-locale?noredirect=1#comment26463_19854), I tried a few different things. I tried editing `/etc/default/locale` and rebooting. I tried two permutations, but neither worked. Originally this file contained

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
```

I edited it include either

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE="en_AU:en"
LC_ALL="en_AU.UTF-8"
```

or

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE="en_AU:en"
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_PAPER="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_AU.UTF-8"
```

I also tried this again, which failed.

```
sudo locale-gen en_AU.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: According to this site http://www.macocd.com/styled/styled-4/index.html locales can are set the first time you SSH to your Pi, and allow setting a default locale.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Yes, I did that at install, then deleting `~/.configureduser` allows you to do it again.

Comment: Did you set a default?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I should have clarified that in the question. I've edited it.

Comment: Take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/33025/locale-settings-are-not-right-how-can-i-reset-them

Comment: Thanks @SteveRobillard! Yes, a solution based on one of those answers worked, although it feels like a dirty workaround. Anyway, it's fine. I answered this question myself, but you put me onto the solution, so I'm happy for you to quote or paraphrase me, then I'll accept your answer. Cheers.

Comment: I am not worried about the reputation,and would have suggested you answer your own question. I understand what you mean by "dirty workaround" but I favor pragmatism  (working but ugly) over broken every day.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and upvotes @SteveRobillard. Once upon a time I would have spent another few hours trying to get the "purer" solution, but no more. My answering suggestion wasn't solely based on reputation, but also because I wouldn't have found the answer so quickly without your directions. Thanks again.

Comment: Just pass it on - and help those who come after you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append `~/.bashrc` with

```
export LANG="en_AU.UTF-8"
export LANGUAGE="en_AU:en"
```

After this the locale was set properly

```
$ locale
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_AU:en
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: This only sets it for the user, not system-wide though.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Correct. You could always modify something like `/etc/bashrc` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're connecting to Pi via ssh, the machine you're connecting from may be exporting it's locale to your pi. This is another avenue. (On that machine, not on the Pi):

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config

# comment out this line
# SendEnv LANG LC_*
```